# Racer does not autocomplete code from prelude

Tags: autocomplete, rust

Racer v2.1.21 does not autocomplete code if I don't specify the full path to the part in Rust prelude.

There is no output when I run this command in a terminal:

```
racer complete Vec::
```

But in this case racer returns autocompletion for `Vec`:

```
racer complete std::vec::Vec
```

Comment: Do you think that's an issue? If so I would suggest to [open a new issue](https://github.com/racer-rust/racer/issues/new) on the github repo instead of asking a question on SO. (Btw: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Don't miss to take the [tour] <3 ).

Comment: For reference, an issue has been opened https://github.com/racer-rust/racer/issues/1033